# Vue router with fetch data

Tags: vue.js

How would I go on to fetch the id as parameter, when using params (not query) on router.push?

I assume my example is not optimal. How would I do it in a better way?

```js
const Cities = Vue.component('city', {
    template: '<h1>{{  }}</h1>',
    created() {
      fetch('')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
  
        this.$router.push({ path: "/:id", params: {  } });
        this.cities = result
        console.log(this.cities)
      });

    },
    data() {
      return {
        cities: { 
          name: "",
          id: ""
        }
      }
    }
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      component: Cities,
      path: '/:id'
    }
  ]
});



new Vue({
  el: '#app'
router
```

Comment: When you use params in `$router.push` you can then later access those params inside the component with `this.$route.params.id` for example. I am not sure if you mean that, so just commenting for now.

Comment: thanks for commenting. I am about to fetch and from each object, i'll use the "id" as the parameter, and "name" to render on the page

Comment: Well, you cannot rely on cities[1], because cities won't be loaded until your fetch resolves. Vue will complain about undefined property errors. First you should check if cities is set and then iterate each city:  `<div v-if="cities"><div v-for="city in cities">{{city.name}}</div></div>`, also, what you define in the data function is a mismatch, it should be an empty array of cities instead of 1 object with id and name.

Comment: You not want to iterate over all cities in the template right ? You just want to display one specific city ?

Comment: yes so I want to display the {{name}} of the city that matches the id of the parameter. they should come from the same object. so the id and city name will match

Comment: Then take a look at my answer it does exactly that :) - well just pointers there

Comment: @l14045 Please take a look at my answer and see if it helps you, if not give some feedback, if yes please accept as correct answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convert Array into Object by id

I am just focusing on displaying the city name here. So you get your result back from the request, I assume the reponse looks like this :

```js
[
  {
    id : "9123102873",
    name : "Alpha"
  },
  {
    id : "1928307239",
    name : "Delta"
  }
]
```

One option would be to create a map out of the array, like

```js
fetch(' ')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((result) => {
       
  const cityMap = {};
  result.map((city) => {
    cityMap[city.id] = city;
  });
  this.cities = cityMap;

});
```

so it looks like

```js
{
  "9123102873" : {
    id : "9123102873",
    name : "Alpha"
  },
  "9123102873" : {
    id : "1928307239",
    name : "Delta"
  }
}
```

Now you can render a city by id like

```
<h1> {{ cities[$route.params.id].name }} </h1>
```

### Careful

But this will probably raise an error since the moment you are entering this component, `cities[whatever].name` will still be undefined until the request is done.

It's also not a good practice to fetch all cities everytime you visit this route, just too filter out one specific city afterwards. Maybe the API supports fetching one city directly ? Or you can take a look at [VUEX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)